# Is there any command to step down one directory in shell?(when there is only one sub-directory)

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

To go up one directory I write cd ..
Is there any command that would work for the reverse situation in which there is only one subdirectory?

Let's say I am in:

dir1/dir2/

dir2 has only one subdirectory dir3

Is there any short cut to step down one directory from dir2 to dir3 without writing the name of subdirectory(dir3)?

Comment: The best shortcut I know of would be to type cd followed by the first letter of the directory, followed by tab to auto complete

Comment: Thank you @Link0352 this is a great option I have not been aware of:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't such command per se, but you can trick the cd command by typing `cd */` ;-)

Comment: I guess there's no command to move back one directory, @polentino: cd */ won't work in ksh :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of my question I was not aware of shells's auto-complete with Tab key.

In this scenario I just type `cd`, press `Tab` and the name of the directory shows up so I can press `Enter` to move to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thought when I was learning shell and wrote a wrapper around cd that does what you want. It grew into something a bit more complicated. If you have folders called folder1 and folder2 you can type: cdd 2
If there is only one folder you can just type: cdd

It also has a similar functionality to ksh's cd paths substitution with 2 args (if at /home/tom, you can type the following to get to /home/bob: cdd tom bob).
It also works like the normal cd command if you pass a folder that exists.

It was written a while ago so it might not be the prettiest, but it works.
It also does an ls at the end which you can remove.

One other thing to note is you can (in bash at least) type the following to go the the previous directory you were in: cd -

```
function cdd()
{
    if [[ $3 != "" ]]; then
        printf "~~~ cdd can only take 1 or 2 arguments, you specified 3 or more\n";
        return;
    else
        if [[ $2 != "" ]]; then
            ARG=$(pwd | sed "s/$1/$2/g");
            cd $ARG;
        else
            if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
                cd $(ls -d */ | head -1);
            else
                if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
                    cd $1;
                else
                    if [[ -d $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "^$1" | head -1) ]]; then
                        cd $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "^$1" | head -1);
                    else
                        if [[ -d $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1/$" | head -1) ]]; then
                            cd $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1/$" | head -1);
                        else
                            if [[ -d $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1" | head -1) ]]; then
                                cd $(ls -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1" | head -1);
                            else
                                if [[ -d $(ls -a -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1" | head -1) ]]; then
                                    cd $(ls -a -F | grep "/$" | grep "$1" | head -1);
                                else
                                    printf "~~~ Folder not found...\n";
                                    return 3;
                                fi;
                            fi;
                        fi;
                    fi;
                fi;
            fi;
        fi;
    fi;
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        ls --color=auto -a --color;
    fi
}
```